# React Native TextInput ReRenders when calling useState Hook inside a custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, textinput

**Description**
When a TextInput component triggers action such as in onChangeText or onKeyPress method which then triggers setState, the component will re render and lose focuse.

**React Native version:**
0.62 (Unable to upgrade due to use of Expo)

**Steps To Reproduce**
Provide a detailed list of steps that reproduce the issue.

1. Create a Custom Wrapper Component simple like
2. Declare useStateHook
3. Pass TextInput to the Wrapper Component either by direct JSX or Custom Component
4. Bind setState function to any of event listeners of TextInput.

**Expected Results**
sets State but does not lose focus or rerenders

**Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository:**
Expo Example
https://snack.expo.io/@ksi9302/1f9369

Hi Guys, this is a bug report I made to React Native.
But I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

**What I've tried so far and doesn't work**

1. Get rid of all styles.
2. make custom input component with class react component, disable shouldComponentUpdate
3. not binding value
4. make different state structure and actually pass within object {}
5. make dummy key

**What I know will work**

- Get rid of custom wrapper and use plain JSX (In other words, not passing TextInput as children component) //Almost impossible when app gets bigger

**Bad Compromise**

- using AutoFocus={true} //on Web works fine, but on Mobile, keyboard flickers a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the wrapper out as it keeps getting rerendered due to the search value changes.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TextInput } from "react-native";

const Test = () => {
  const handleChange = e => {
    setSearch(e);
  };
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(null);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <TextInput
        value={search}
        onChangeText={e => {
          handleChange(e);
        }}
        placeholder="type here"
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper = props => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          display: "flex",
        }}
      >
        {props.children}
      </View>
    );
  };

export default Test;
```

Comment: Hi D10S, Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, it then works fine. However, with my real project, this approach presents a lot of problem, because within the Wrapper component, there's another customer component which utilizes a lot of functions declared within the top component, if I have to move all these components out of the parent component, I will have to pass a bunch of props basically losing the best advantage of declaring a child component inside the parent component. Is this just discouraged way in React programming or do you expect this issue to be solved in the future?

Comment: What is the problem passing a lot of props?? anyhow, If I get you right, what you need is to use HOC. Please note that if parent and child sit in the same component, there is no logic in splitting them,

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info, I will look in to HOC. I got it working now somehow though. In my code, The Wrapper has <Header> and inside <Header>, I then Have my <FunctionButtons> which includes TextInput, Now, I've moved the Wrapper out side and Header is an imported component from the start, For this FunctionButtons Component, I just moved the JSX inside Header and the problem is gone, I don't really see why returning the exact same JSX from a nested child component since it's the same code. Well, I guess I'll have to do some homework on it.. Thanks a lot again for your help!

Comment: @D10S  I'm experiencing this same problem.  Indeed, removing "the wrapper" worked for me.  What I dont understand is WHY this is a thing. Why can I not wrap my TextInput using useState at the sametime? I'm not connecting dots...